# When authentication fails, send different answer according to whether username exists

Tags: jpa, https, basic-authentication, quarkus

It is easy enough to set up basic authentication with JPA thanks to the related Quarkus [tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jpa).

But with the provided tutorial, when authentication fails, Quarkus sends a no-content 401 response, irrespective of whether the username provided in the request header exists (and the password did not match) or does not exist. I mean that Quarkus answers in exactly the same way (AFAICT) to `curl -i -u "user:invalidpassword" localhost:8080/v0/users/me` and  `curl -i -u "invaliduser:somepassword" localhost:8080/v0/users/me` (assuming `user` is a valid username). I’d like these two answers to differ.

How can I tell Quarkus to send a different answer, when authentication fails, according to whether the username exists or does not exist? For example, send a 401 code with content “Invalid password” VS a 401 code with content “Unknown user”.

There are numerous discussions on SO about what codes one should send or whether one should indicate to the caller whether the username exists, and how to mitigate enumeration attacks in that case. But I could find no question about how to implement different answers with Quarkus.

I realize I could implement my own security interception and replace entirely the one provided by Quarkus, but I hope I do not need to go to such extreme solution: the Quarkus basic authentication facility is exactly what I need, apart from this little tweak.

Comment: For security reasons you usually don't want to reveal if a user account exists or not. Therefore the current behavior of your server is in my opinion the best solution and you should not change it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Robert's comment; that said, if you'd like to customize the processing of the authentication failure (for example - provide a more informative secure log message, etc) then you can do it by disabling a [proactive authentication](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#proactive-authentication) and registering a custom JAX-RS `ExceptionMapper`:

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import io.quarkus.security.AuthenticationFailedException;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFailedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<AuthenticationFailedException> {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(AuthenticationFailedException exception) {
        return Response.status(401).header("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Quarkus\"").build();
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want to answer the question because you think I should not do that? If you intended to answer the question, there is something I miss: how can I determine whether the authentication failed because of a non-existing username or because of an incorrect password? According to my tests, the exception looks identical in both cases.